# GNU make interdependent predependencies

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu

I am trying to write a make rule with pre-dependencies which are inter related.

```
a: b $(FILES)

b: $(FILE_1)
  $(eval FILES := some_function_using_file($(FILE_1)))

$(FILES):
  do something ...
```

Basically, I need $(FILE_1) to get $(FILES). When make first reads in the file, this rule below does not exist because $(FILES) is not defined initially but gets evaluated dynamically.

```
$(FILES):
  do something ...
```

Is there a way to make this work? I want to dynamically create $(FILES) and then run its rule.

Answer (score 0):

The targets get evaluated before any of them run. Your best bet is to generate the list before that happens.

```
FILES = $(shell ls) new.txt

all: $(FILES)

$(FILES):
  echo $@
```

If you're really desperate you could generate another makefile from within the makefile and call another copy of make.

Comment: Or [`include`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) that generated makefile.

Comment: Include would work before making any targets but I don't think you can do it within a target like in OPs example.